# How long do expansion anchors last?

Tags: anchor, drywall-anchor, lamp

I have a wall sconce in my room, which is attached to the wall with two expansion anchors (dowels). They look well-fixed, but, AFAIK, they are about 20 years old. Do you know, how long dowels last, and whether I should replace them because of their age?

Comment: Are these wooden dowels? Plastic? Do you know anything about the brand or trype that was used?

Comment: If an expansion anchor is installed properly and sized correctly for the load (and dry) I haven't seen one fail. If the load has high vibration that is a diferent story also if it is a wet location wood can rot steel rusts. But if properly installed I have found wood plugs that were over 100 years old even lead in cement that was fine after 70-80 years when the lag bolt rusted off.

Comment: @Sean, they are metallic!

Answer (score 1):

I found the Wood kind of my Grandfather in my House. They are just fine. The plastic once should last even longer. Don't fix them if they don't need fixing!